# Injecting configuration in Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, identityserver4

I have a requester that is responsible for connecting to the Azure Table Store. It takes a configuration object, containing connection strings and table names pulled from `appsettings.json`:

```
internal class UserRequester : IUserRequester {

    private CloudTableClient Client { get; }
    private string TableName { get; }

    public UserRequester(IOptions<TableStoreConfiguration> configuration) {
        CloudStorageAccount account = configuration.Value.GetCloudStorageAccount();
        Client = account.CreateCloudTableClient(new TableClientConfiguration());
        TableName = configuration.Value.UserLogin;
    }
}
```

In my `Startup.cs`, I have defined this object and the configuration like this:

```
IIdentityServerBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(certData);
builder.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Identities.Get());
builder.AddInMemoryApiResources(Apis.GetResources());
builder.AddInMemoryApiScopes(Apis.GetScopes());

builder.Services.Configure<TableStoreConfiguration>(Configuration);
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserRequester, UserRequester>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, PasswordValidator>();
```

**Edit:**
I'm also including my host builder (`Program.cs`):

```
public class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

However, when I attempt to call `https://localhost:{PORT}/access_token` (i.e. call into the service), I get an exception in the `UserRequester` constructor:

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Debugging into the code, I see that the constructor for my `TableStoreConfiguration` is never called, which means that the connection string is null.

I assume there's something wrong with how I'm setting up my dependency injector but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: How is the host builder set up?

Comment: @HugoQuintelaRibeiro Sorry, I don't think I understand your question. What do you mean by "host builder"?

Comment: I mean Program.cs (where the host builder is setup) and also how do you configure TableStorageConfiguration (probably in Startup.ConfigureServices).

Comment: @HugoQuintelaRibeiro I added the host builder. The problem I'm having is that the `TableStoreConfiguration` constructor is never called so the inner values inside are all null.

Comment: Still... the problem may be in the way the host builder is setup to load TableStoreConfiguration...

Comment: That's my though as well but I'm not sure where else to insert the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was with my `TableStoreConfiguration` object. I had neglected to make the connection string and table name public, so the configuration method couldn't assign them any values. Changing it to this fixed the issue:

```
internal class TableStoreConfiguration {

    public string UserLogin { get; set; }

    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public CloudStorageAccount GetCloudStorageAccount() {
        return CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
    }
}
```